# JQuery: Multiple simple modals opened on the same page at the same time

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I use the simple modal jquery plugin. Is it possible to have multiple modals opened on the same page at the same time. If not out of the box, how would the core plugin code need to be modified to enable this?

Comment: do they have to be "modal" locking the screen?

Comment: I have never tried 2 at the same time with out of the box modal dialog, but if it doesn't work you can always put a black div in the background with 100% height 100% width with .5 opacity , that will lock screen